# Azcopy migrate content from S3 with Content type

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

Am trying to migrate my s3 objects to Azure Blob storage. The command am using is

> azcopy cp "s3url/10588.mp4" "azureurl/10588.mp4"

This is working as expected, but the contents in Blob storage are stored with content type, binary/octet-stream.

i tried adding content type flag as

> azcopy cp "s3url/10588.mp4" "azureurl/10588.mp4" --content-type
> "video/mp4"

but am getting

failed to parse user input due to error: no-guess-mime-type is not supported while copying from service to service

Can anyone let me know how to migrate a entire folder from S3 to Azure using azcopy with content type preserved?

Comment: Please try to add options `--no-guess-mime-type`.

Comment: Thanks Jim for the response, I am migrating an entire folder, is it possible to auto detect the content type by azcopy?

Comment: And when i tried --no-guess-mime-type, am getting failed to parse user input due to error: no-guess-mime-type is not supported while copying from service to service

Comment: Could you tell me which command you run get the error?